# Error: "Capacity was less than the current size" with ASP.NET DataPager control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I've got an ASP.NET ListView with a DataPager as per this code:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="TicketsPerPersonListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            -- No Records Found --
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td>
                    <a href="viewticket.aspx?id=<%#Eval("ticket_id")%>">#<%# Eval("TicketID")%>-
                        <%# Eval("ShortDesc")%></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("StatusName")%>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 60px;">
                    <%# Eval("StatusDescription")%>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 60px;">
                    <%# Eval("TimeLastAction")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Title
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: right; padding-right: 60px;">
                            Current Status
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: right; padding-right: 60px;">
                            Latest Action
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: right; padding-right: 60px;">
                            Last Viewed
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <div class="pagination">
                                <asp:DataPager ID="TicketsPerPersonDataPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="TicketsPerPersonListView"
                                    PageSize="10">
                                    <Fields>
                                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField FirstPageText="&lt;&lt;" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"
                                            ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                                        <asp:NumericPagerField CurrentPageLabelCssClass="graybutton pagelink active" NumericButtonCssClass="graybutton pagelink" />
                                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField LastPageText="&gt;&gt;" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"
                                            ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                                    </Fields>
                                </asp:DataPager>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    <tr style="display: table-row;">
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" EnablePaging="True" SelectMethod="FindByUserID"
        TypeName="Xyratex.XCS.Services.TicketService" StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex"
        MaximumRowsParameterName="maximumRows" SelectCountMethod="CountByUserID">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="userID" DbType="Int64" DefaultValue="79" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="custID" ControlID="DDCaller" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True"
                DefaultValue="" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="company" ControlID="DDCompany" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True"
                DefaultValue="" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="owner" ControlID="DDOwner" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True"
                DefaultValue="" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="action" ControlID="DDAction" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True"
                DefaultValue="" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="status" ControlID="DDCurrentStatus" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True"
                DefaultValue="" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The VB.NET code that provides the ObjectDataSource with data is thus:

```
    ''' <summary>
''' Finds all the <see cref="Xyratex.XCS.Model.Tickets.Ticket" /> objects belonging to the specified user ID
''' </summary>
''' <param name="userID">The id of the user to find tickets for</param>
''' <param name="startRowIndex">The starting index of the portion of the recordset</param>
''' <param name="maximumRows">The maximum amount of rows to return</param>
''' <param name="custID">The id of the customer to find tickets for</param>
''' <param name="company">The company name to find tickets for</param>
''' <param name="owner">The owner to find tickets for</param>
''' <param name="action">The action to find tickets for</param>
''' <param name="status">The status of tickets to find.</param>
''' <returns>A <see cref="System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of Xyratex.XCS.Model.Tickets.Ticket)" /> object</returns>
''' <remarks>XY01\rpenfold 30 January 2012</remarks>
Public Function FindByUserID(ByVal userID As Long,
                             ByVal startRowIndex As Long,
                             ByVal maximumRows As Long,
                             ByVal custID As Long?,
                             ByVal company As String,
                             ByVal owner As Integer?,
                             ByVal action As Char?,
                             ByVal status As Long?) As List(Of LightWeightTicket) Implements ITicketRepository.FindByUserID
    'Start a new session and run the query
    Using session As NHibernate.ISession = SessionFactory.GetNewSession()
        Dim query As NHibernate.IQuery = session.GetNamedQuery("Select_AllTickets_ByUserID_RyanTest")
        query.SetInt64("user_id", userID)
        Select Case custID.HasValue
            Case True
                query.SetInt64("cust_id", custID.Value)
            Case False
                query.SetString("cust_id", Nothing) 'SetString makes it NULL
        End Select
        Select Case String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(company)
            Case True
                query.SetString("company", Nothing)
            Case False
                query.SetString("company", company) 'SetString makes it NULL
        End Select
        Select Case owner.HasValue
            Case True
                query.SetInt32("owner", owner.Value)
            Case False
                query.SetString("owner", Nothing) 'SetString makes it NULL
        End Select
        Select Case action.HasValue
            Case True
                query.SetCharacter("action", action.Value)
            Case False
                query.SetString("action", Nothing) 'SetString makes it NULL
        End Select
        Select Case status.HasValue
            Case True
                query.SetInt64("status", status.Value)
            Case False
                query.SetString("status", Nothing) 'SetString makes it NULL
        End Select
        query.SetInt64("startRowIndex", startRowIndex)
        query.SetInt64("maximumRows", maximumRows)
        Return New List(Of LightWeightTicket)(query.List(Of LightWeightTicket)())
    End Using
End Function
```

When I load the page, I receive the error "Capacity was less than the current size". The stack trace is per thus:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: capacity was less than the current size.
```

Parameter name: value]
    System.Collections.ArrayList.set_Capacity(Int32 value) +9360651
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +712
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +35
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
    System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +113
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls() +55
    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496

Does anyone know what to do about this?

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the question, but why do you always use Select Case? This is simpler and easier on the eyes: `If owner.HasValue Then ... Else ... End If`

Comment: I prefer Select Case :o)

Answer (score 3):

I solved it!

The count method was returning a System.Int64. When this was amended to a System.Int32, it worked!

Comment: Thank you! I just experienced the same problem! and it helped me.